# ggpairs plot with heatmap of correlation values

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally, aesthetics

My question is twofold;

I have a ggpairs plot with the default `upper = list(continuous = cor)` and I would like to colour the tiles by correlation values (exactly like what ggcorr does).

I have this: [image: ggpairs plot of daily flows]
I would like the correlation values of the plot above to be coloured like this: [image: ggcorr heatmap of correlation values]

```
library(GGally)

sample_df <- data.frame(replicate(7,sample(0:5000,100)))
colnames(sample_df) <- c("KUM", "MHP", "WEB", "OSH", "JAC", "WSW", "gaugings")

ggpairs(sample_df, lower = list(continuous = "smooth"))  
ggcorr(sample_df, label = TRUE, label_round = 2)
```

I had a brief go at trying to use `upper = list(continuous = wrap(ggcorr)` but didn't have any luck and, given that both functions return plot calls, I don't think that's the right path?

I am aware that I could build this in ggplot (e.g. [Sandy Muspratt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075305/what%C2%B4s-the-best-way-to-do-a-correlation-matrix-plot-like-this)) but given that the GGally package already has the functionality I am looking for I thought I might be overlooking something.

---

More broadly, I would like to know how we, or if we can, call the correlation values? A simpler option may be to colour the labels rather than the tile (i.e. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716567/use-ggpairs-to-create-this-plot) using colour rather than size) but I need a variable to assign to colour...

Being able to call the correlation values to use in other plots would be handy although I suppose I could just recalculate them myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A possible solution is to get the list of colors from the `ggcorr` correlation matrix plot and to set these colors as background in the upper tiles of the `ggpairs`  matrix of plots.

```
library(GGally)   
library(mvtnorm)
# Generate data
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
p <- 7
A <- matrix(runif(p^2)*2-1, ncol=p) 
Sigma <- cov2cor(t(A) %*% A)
sample_df <- data.frame(rmvnorm(n, mean=rep(0,p), sigma=Sigma))
colnames(sample_df) <- c("KUM", "MHP", "WEB", "OSH", "JAC", "WSW", "gaugings")

# Matrix of plots
p1 <- ggpairs(sample_df, lower = list(continuous = "smooth"))  
# Correlation matrix plot
p2 <- ggcorr(sample_df, label = TRUE, label_round = 2)
```

The correlation matrix plot is:

[image]

```
# Get list of colors from the correlation matrix plot
library(ggplot2)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
colors <- g2$grobs[[6]]$children[[3]]$gp$fill

# Change background color to tiles in the upper triangular matrix of plots 
idx <- 1
for (k1 in 1:(p-1)) {
  for (k2 in (k1+1):p) {
    plt <- getPlot(p1,k1,k2) +
     theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = colors[idx], color="white"),
           panel.grid.major = element_line(color=colors[idx]))
    p1 <- putPlot(p1,plt,k1,k2)
    idx <- idx+1
}
}
print(p1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can map a background colour to the cell by writing a quick custom function that can be passed directly to `ggpairs`. This involves calculating the correlation between the pairs of variables, and then matching to some user specified colour range.

```
my_fn <- function(data, mapping, method="p", use="pairwise", ...){

              # grab data
              x <- eval_data_col(data, mapping$x)
              y <- eval_data_col(data, mapping$y)

              # calculate correlation
              corr <- cor(x, y, method=method, use=use)

              # calculate colour based on correlation value
              # Here I have set a correlation of minus one to blue, 
              # zero to white, and one to red 
              # Change this to suit: possibly extend to add as an argument of `my_fn`
              colFn <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"), interpolate ='spline')
              fill <- colFn(100)[findInterval(corr, seq(-1, 1, length=100))]

              ggally_cor(data = data, mapping = mapping, ...) + 
                theme_void() +
                theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill=fill))
            }
```

Using the data in Marco's answer:

```
library(GGally)    # version: ‘1.4.0’

p1 <- ggpairs(sample_df, 
                   upper = list(continuous = my_fn),
                   lower = list(continuous = "smooth"))
```

Which gives:

[image]

---

A followup question [Change axis labels of a modified ggpairs plot (heatmap of correlation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930523/change-axis-labels-of-a-modified-ggpairs-plot-heatmap-of-correlation/60935938?noredirect=1#comment107808516_60935938) noted that post plot updating of the `theme` resulted in the `panel.background` colours being removed. This can be fixed by removing the `theme_void` and removing the grid lines within the theme. i.e. change the relevant bit to (**NOTE** that this fix is not required for ggplot2 v3.3.0)

```
ggally_cor(data = data, mapping = mapping, ...) + 
           theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill=fill, colour=NA),
                 panel.grid.major = element_blank())
```

Comment: is there any possibility to change the x-axis labels with your solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930523/change-axis-labels-of-a-modified-ggpairs-plot-heatmap-of-correlation

Comment: @user20650: if I add a theme with `+ theme_minimal()` to `p1`, the `panel.background` colors are again removed. Any advice where to add the theme such that it is not eventually removed? Many thanks!

Comment: Hi @mavericks; can you explain your expected outcome please as i'd expect theme_minimal to strip the panel colour (i.e. `p=ggplot()+theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="red")); p ; 
p  +theme_minimal()`) . But yes it can be / is a bit of a pain setting theme elements across ggpairs.

Comment: @mavericks; there will be a way to do this more simply but you can piece the parts together to get the final effect (which I think you want). Add a `theme_minimal` to the lower & diagonal plots and remove the   `strip.background` . So try ; `ggpairs(sample_df, 
    upper = list(continuous = my_fn),
    lower = list(continuous = function(...) ggally_points(...)+theme_minimal()),
    diag =  list(continuous = function(...) ggally_densityDiag(...)+theme_minimal()))+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank())`

Comment: @user20650 thanks a lot for your input! Just added [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196950/ggpairs-plot-with-heatmap-of-correlation-values-with-significance-stars-and-cust/62196951#62196951) summarizing your previous advice which greatly helped me with my plots! Thanks again