# R GGally::ggpairs - how to adjust by BH and modify stars (*) significance levels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, p-value, ggally

I usually provide a simple correlation matrix plot as the output of correlation analyses using `psych::corr.test` and `corrplot`.

Now I am required to accompany it by a more detailed matrix plot with densities and scatter plots with slopes, for colleagues to be able to interpret the original plot better.

For this latter purpose I use `GGally::ggpairs`, which gives me all I need. My problem here is that I do not seem to be able to specify the exact same details I do with `psych::corr.test` and `corrplot`...

See my MWE with `mtcars`:

I first generate my correlation and pvalue matrices using Pearson's correlation and BH for adjusting.

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars
correlation_result <- psych::corr.test(mtcars[,1:7], method="pearson", adjust=mymethod, alpha=.05)
correlation_matrix <- correlation_result$r
pvalue_matrix <- correlation_result$p
```

I then produce my original simple plot; I just want to show `*` and `**` for p-values lower than 0.05 and 0.01 respectively:

```
#1
grDevices::pdf(file="test1.pdf", height=10, width=10)
corrplot::corrplot(correlation_matrix, p.mat=pvalue_matrix, sig.level=c(0.01, 0.05), method="circle", type="upper",
                   insig="label_sig", pch.cex=2, order="original", pch.col="white", tl.col="black",
                   tl.pos="td", tl.cex=2, cl.cex=2, diag=FALSE, mar=c(0,0,2,2))
grDevices::dev.off()
```

I get this plot, which is exactly what I need:
[image: test1]

Finally, I make my detailed plot with `GGally::ggpairs`, but there are a couple of details I cannot specify:

1. While I can specify Pearson's correlation, there is no `adjust` parameter for BH p-value adjust
2. The asterisks shown just follow the following criteria, and I do not seem to be able to change it with the `stars` parameter: `***` if the p-value is < 0.001, `**` if the p-value is < 0.01, `*` if the p-value is < 0.05, `.` if the p-value is < 0.10

I use this code:

```
#2
grDevices::pdf(file="test2.pdf", height=15, width=15)
print(
  GGally::ggpairs(mtcars, columns=1:7,
                  lower=list(continuous=GGally::wrap("smooth", alpha=0.5, size=3)),
                  diag=list(continuous=GGally::wrap("densityDiag", alpha=0.5)),
                  upper=list(continuous=GGally::wrap("cor", method="pearson", stars=TRUE, size=6))) +
    ggplot2::theme_light() +
    ggplot2::theme(axis.text=ggplot2::element_text(size=15),
                   strip.text=ggplot2::element_text(size=20,face="bold"))
)
grDevices::dev.off()
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: test2]

Aesthetically it is exactly what I need, but the significance shown does not match my original plot... I want to be able to adjust the p-values, and show significance for just my 2 cutoffs of 0.05 and 0.01... is there any way to do it (preferably with `GGally::ggpairs`)?

Comment: I am tinkering around with stuff from this question, which someone else might find useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196950/ggpairs-plot-with-heatmap-of-correlation-values-with-significance-stars-and-cust

Comment: the problem with the `cor_fun` used in the question linked is that it does correlation on every pair, so adjusting every pair does not adjust the same as the whole matrix with `psych::corr.test`